# Finding truth of logic statement

Tags: logic

I'm attempting to evaluate the truth of the following statement:

∃a∀b((a < b) → (a^2 < b^2)), where a and b are real numbers.

I have tested multiple values (whole numbers and fractions) and have come to the conclusion that the statement is true. However, I "feel" like the statement may not be true and my thinking about evaluating it is not robust enough. Could anyone provide some direction for me?

Comment: This is not a full answer, but have you tried applying induction? It smells like an induction homework/test-question. Just testing it for a few values is obviously not a full proof.

Comment: Induction is out of the question: it’s a statement about real numbers, not integers.

Comment: You are trying to show that **there is** an $a$ with a certain property. If you can show that (say) $10$ has the property, you will have completely finished. Is it true that if $10\lt b$, then $100\lt b^2$? Sure, on the positive reals, $f(x)=x^2$ is an increasing function.

Comment: I see. Well, perhaps and perhaps not. This paper seems to allow it in principle: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/realinduction.pdf. Anyway, my mistake. I didn't realize the proposition might be false!

Comment: @AndréNicolas I may be misreading the statement, but does this not mean that for every b there will be an a<b and a^2<b^2. If the question was changed to ∃a∃b then your answer would be applicable? I'm not saying your wrong, but that is how I thought the question is to be read.

Comment: @Huss No.  You're switching the quantifiers.  The statement you're describing is $\forall b \exists a ( a < b \implies a^2 < b^2 )$.

Comment: The proposition is true. For the rest, I was assuming that by *induction* you meant one of the usual varieties, as the suggestion would otherwise be more than a bit misleading.

Comment: Apart from needing to pay attention to parentheses, logic statements are read, like English, from left to right. The sentence says **there is an $a$** such that $\dots$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks, I'm still learning. If you wanted to put your comment into an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We read the assertion for left to right. You are trying to show that there **exists** a number $a$ which has a certain property. What property? That whatever number $b$ is, if $a\lt b$ then $a^2\lt b^2$.

If you can show that (say) $10$ has the property, you will be **completely** finished. 
To show that there **exists** an $a$ with a certain property, all you need to do is toexhibit an $a$ that has the property. (There may also be *indirect* ways to show such an $a$ exists.)

So is it true that for any (all) $b$, if  $10<b$, then $100<b^2$? Sure, on the positive reals, $f(x)=x^2$ is an increasing function.

**Remark:** Pick $a=-17$. Then $a$ does not have the required property. For $-17 \lt 2$, but $(-17)^2 \gt 2^2$.  So there are "bad" $a$. But the statement just claimed that there is a good $a$.

You might note that we could have picked $a=0$, for $0$ has the desired property. Actually, nothing smaller than $0$ has the property.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: What happens if take $a$ to be $0$?